# PhpStorm xdebug - Waiting for incoming connection with ide key

Tags: php, xampp, phpstorm, xdebug

I have problem with making

```
xampp-laravel-xdebugger-phpstorm
```

works.

Got

```
PhpStorm xdebug - Waiting for incoming connection with ide key '17269'
```

My config below

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I did all that on xdebug by placing my `php.ini` I was told to do, exactly:

[image]

Did everything.

And I looked for others topics on StackOverflow for this and other websites, tried many solutions, and doesn't work. Solutions like ticking 'can accept external path' in xdebug config, using port 9000, ticking 'use path mapping' in server config on PhpStorm, placing in php ini things like new 10 xdebug settings itd..., nothing helps

I do not know what to do more

Comment: Please try this setup:

https://gist.github.com/odan/1abe76d373a9cbb15bed

Comment: Or you might want to take a look at this answer, it's a tutorial on how to setup XDebug with PHPStorm https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45019201/phpstorm-debug-with-laravel-homestead-not-working/45019239#45019239